# Union of different types and sizes of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, unions, strict-aliasing

```
typedef struct  {  char   ch;  int   num;  }  st_t;
typedef union   {  char *pch;  st_t *pst;  }  un_t;

st_t st;
st.ch = 's';

un_t un = { &st.ch };
*un.pch = 'u';

printf("%c\n", un.pst->ch);  // expect: print the letter 'u'
```

As far as I know, the address of the first member of the struct and the address of the struct itself are the same, so `un` could both point to `st` and `st.ch` at the same time by accessing `pst` and `pch`. However, the C99 standard seems that it never explicitly says [the sizes of different types of pointers are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-sizes). Then, my concern is that will the code be corrupted such as violating strict aliasing rules, being undefined behavior, etc.?

Comment: Note: C99 is not the current C standard. That would be C11. You might want to read about pointer conversions, etc. One issue you could encounter is violation of the effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule as you mentioned. That would invoke undefined behaviour (UB is not an issue by itself, but the result of violation of a rule/constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
un_t un = {&st.ch};
*un.pch = 'u';
```

assigns the address of the member ch of the struct to the member pch of the union, and that pointer is then used to write a character to that address. This is completely correct.

There is a problem with the line that follows:

```
printf("%c\n", un.pst->ch);
```

The member of the union, other than the one that was last stored into, is read.
The following may be a trap<sup>1</sup> representation<sup>2</sup>:

```
un.pst
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.6.1 General 5 )
Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored
value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does
not have character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is produced
by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that
does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. 50) Such a representation is called
a trap representation.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members 3 footnote 95) )
If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

Comment: A more common problem on typical 32/64 bit CPUs are alignment issues.

Comment: @Olaf Not in this case since the pointer points to the struct.

Comment: Hmm, yes, you are correct here. I looked at the more general case. Dereferencing would violate effective type rule (I preferr the term used in the standard).

Comment: @2501 If this is an UB, then is the method provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) still valid? (See **So how do I get around this?**)

Comment: @KevinDong Strict aliasing isn't an issue here. The code you have presented is defined on most modern machines. From the perspective of the C language, it may trap, this is possible on a unusual architecture.

Comment: @KevinDong: I smell the haut-gout of an XY-problem. What are you actually trying to do? The snippets don't look like a typical design pattern. In general it is better not to become too fancy with `union`s or macros. Both are typical flaws of unexperienced programmers (no offence!)

Comment: @Olaf Oh, I am implementing sentinel nodes for linked lists. For instance, `struct _node { void *lnk; int val; }` and `union _sentinel { void *ptr; struct _node *pnode } ` where both `ptr` and `pnode` point to the same address.

Comment: @2501: The code is UB by the standard and an compiler might exploit that. gcc for instance is well known to only accept the standard and don't care much about "expected behaviour" or "common practice".

Comment: @KevinDong You can avoid this by using casts which actually avoid trap representations since the type isn't reinterpreted.

Comment: @Olaf No, this is idiomatic type punning. It is defined as long as you avoid traps, which I dare say, don't exists between char and struct pointers on modern systems. Of course the code isn't portable.

Comment: @KevinDong: Without a complete description this is impossible to decide (and it is TO here anyway). But I'm certain there are other ways which don't rely on problematic code.

Comment: @Olaf It can avoid trap representations by using type casting, **but** it will pop up another serious problem, strict aliasing, because two different pointers point to the same address.

Comment: @2501: You may pun the pointer types, but not the objects they point to. It's friday evening and I'm too exhaused to check in the standard right now, but I have a bad feeling about this. And normally I can trust my spider-sense (ok, enough movie quotes). I would not use this constuction. I'll leave it at this for now.

Comment: @KevinDong Strict aliasing is never an issue here. char pointer may point to anything, and the struct pointer is pointing to the struct of the same type.

Comment: @Olaf Take a fresh look at the code tomorrow, try to write an example yourself and you'll see it valid.

Comment: @2501 Yes. The code snippet cannot, but actually it does in my project because I wrote code like this to avoid strict aliasing problem.;-) It seems that these two problems cannot be solved at a same time. (See the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373964/opposite-keyword-of-restrict-in-c) I posted several days ago).

Comment: @KevinDong If you're worried about different code in your project, then post a new question with a minimal example that reproduces the problem. And ask a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

While a construct like this is not strictly conforming to the standard regarding pointer sizes, in practice the most common implementations (i.e. msvc, gcc/linux) do use the same representation for non-function pointers.

So on those implementation it should work as you would expect.

Comment: I'd be very carefull with "**most** implementations". Most implementations are for MCUs which can have all kinds of specialities. e.g. for x86-16bit there are different pointer widths. But we don't have to get that far. Alignment can be different for the pointers.

Comment: @Olaf Fair enough.  Edited to " the most common implementations", i.e. what beginners are most likely to come across.

Comment: Hmm, the beginners in my embedded class could have started with PIC, C51, etc ;-) (yes, that was nit-picking and I'll stop right here;-)

Comment: @Olaf: Even on platforms which extend the C language by adding additional storage classes, and where pointers to different storage classes have different sizes (e.g. on the 8086, "near" pointers are two bytes while "far" pointers are four bytes), it is *very* rare for implementations to have the size or representation of a data pointer vary according to the type (rather than storage class) of the target object.

Answer (score 0):

The C Standard attempts to define characteristics, features, and guarantees which are required of all conforming implementations; it does not endeavor to describe most of the the useful characteristics and features that are common to 99% of implementations, but which are not required.

On the vast majority of implementations, all data pointers use the same representation, so given `thingType *foo=xxx; void *vfoo = foo;`, both `foo`
and `vfoo` will hold the same pattern of bits.  Before the days of aggressive
optimizers, such implementations would quite usefully allow any kind of data
pointer to be accessed using a `void**`, so one could write functions like:

```
int realloc_if_possible(void **p, int newsize)
{
  void *temp = realloc(*p, newsize);
  if (!temp) return -1;
  *p = temp;
  return 0;
}
```

but since the C Standard doesn't require compilers to recognize aliasing if
the function is passed the address of any kind of pointer other than a void*,
many modern compilers no longer support such constructs unless all type-based
aliasing optimizations are disabled.

Comment: How about an union containing sometype* and void*? Does this kind of type punning conform to the standard since void* should compatible to any other types of  pointers?

Comment: @KevinDong: That would fall in the category of behaviors which are supported by 99% of implementations, but which the Standard does not require.